# Getting text value of an element with XPATH

Tags: python, xpath

I want to grab text values of all buttons on the page like this:

```
all_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').getText()
```

But I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

How can I extract the names of the buttons into the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` to get the text of all buttons.

```py
all_buttons = [button.text for button in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements` returns a **list** of web element objects while `text` (not `.getText()`, this is from Java) method can be applied on a **single** web element object only to extract it text content.
So, to extract texts from all the elements in the list you need to iterate over the list extracting text from each web element object as following:

```py
all_buttons_texts = []
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
for element in elements:
    element_text = element.text
    all_buttons_texts.append(element_text)
```

Or in a shorter way, as mentioned by Fastnlight

```py
all_buttons = [button.text for button in driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')]
```